# Simeple makefile - No rules for object

Tags: c++, makefile, rule

Here is my makefile:

Name of file: L2_Z2.make

```
CXX=g++ 
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -o
OBJS=L2_Z2__test.cpp

all: L2_Z2
L2_Z2: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) ./L2_Z2 $(OBJS)

clean:
    rm -f ./Zad_2 *~
```

After execution command: make L2_Z2

I got error: "No rules for object L2_Z2"

Where is my fault?
Thanks for advice.

Comment: You either have to use this with `make -f L2_Z2.make` or rename  it to `Makefile`.

Comment: Hmmm, you didn't define a rule for `%.o: %.cpp`, so make complains.

Comment: @nickie - `Nul` Character.. hmm

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.  All I was saying is that `make` assumes the make file is named `Makefile`.  If it is not, you need to use the `-f` flag.

Comment: @nickie - Make with `-f` found a `NUL` character at first line. and ignore all.

`:1: warning: NUL character seen; rest of line ignored`
`:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: @JanCzarny Also, did you use `\t` TAB characters for the indents after `L2_Z2: $(OBJS)` and `clean:` rules? These are essential to make rules ! Also note nickie is right about how to call it correctly.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, yes. You can check here: http://pastebin.com/RmfZEKZd

Comment: I copied to another file and it work.